# Where has the Autodesk.Revit.Application.ActiveDocument.Create method gone?

Tags: vb.net, revit, revit-api

Where is the `Application.ActiveDocument` Namespace in the 2014 Revit API?

I'm trying to draw lines in the Revit model under a sketch plane using the API, and at this point, I'm failing.  For most things 'Revit', I follow Jeremy Tammik at [The Building Coder](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com).  This time however, he's led me in the wrong direction due to Autodesk updating/modifying namespaces.  I've converted to VB.NET [some C# he posted a while back](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/11/model-line-creation.html), probably before 2011, that creates a sketch plane and draws the lines.  The problem is the namespaces he's used to instantiate the objects have been changed.  For example, he dimensions a variable 'X' as an `Autodesk.Revit.Application` object, however at this point, that namespace has been changed to `Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application`.

I've created a `Creation` document and `Application` and I'm trying to set the document equal to `AutoDesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.ActiveDocument.Create` method, but it doesn't seem to be there anymore.  I've searched high and low on the Google, but I can't seem to find anything.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a C# snippet showing you how to access it.  Each entity, Application and Document, has a separation between the UI part (`UIApplication`/`UIDocument`) and the database part (`Application`/`Document`).  Which document is active is a matter of the UI so you first have to get the `UIApplication` object from your command arguments.  Then from there you get the `UIDocument` object.  And finally from that you can access the database `Document` object.

```
public void CreateSketchPlane(ExternalCommandData commandData)
{
    UIApplication uiApplication = commandData.Application;
    UIDocument activeUiDocument = uiApplication.ActiveUIDocument;
    Document document = activeUiDocument.Document;

    //document.Create.NewSketchPlane(...
}
```

FYI - `Application.ActiveDocument` was *not* a namespace.  `Application` was a *class* and `ActiveDocument` was a *property* of that class just as now you have the *class* `UIApplication` and its *property* `ActiveUIDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the old creation methods have been moved to static Create() methods in each class.

For example, the method to create a line is now Line.Create()

Take a look at the "What's New" document for each API year to see what's changed